# Prove or disprove irrational numbers

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

If x^(1/3) is an irrational number, then x is also irrational.

I tried using contrapositive, but it's not the right way.

Answer (score 2):

This is plainly not true. $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is irrational.